# Which Hibernate event is called before constraints check?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, events

I need to calculate non-nullable column value before insert takes place. I have setup something like :

```java
@Log
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class EventDispatcher implements PreInsertEventListener {

    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {

        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

        log.info("Prepending listener for EventType.PRE_INSERT");
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_INSERT).prependListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event) {
        log.info("onPreInsert");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Log shows my listener is registered but below exception occurs before `onPreInsert` is hit. Unfortunately, this event seems to be fired fired only after constraint checks are done. So I get this kind of error :

`org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : ...`

I tried several other events but was unable to find any that got fired early enough.

`Note: the above listener code works: when I set required properties before saving the entity, I can see the onPreInsert in the logs.`

Using the `@PrePersist` JPA annotation works since it is called upstream, before entering Hibernate stuff. But since I need some Hibernate events anyway, I'd prefer not to mix stuff and have a common place for all events callbacks.

Any hint ?

BTW, I'd happily take some link(s) describing Hibernate events logic. I'm struggling to find any documentation beside the event list ...

Comment: Hibernate implements JPA, so it seems prePersist is 'in' hibernate code. They chose to fire the PrePersist event nearer to the persist call, while onPreInsert is fired just before the insert statement gets sent to the database; they have BeanValidation (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/beanvalidation/BeanValidationEventListener.html ) implementing the PreInsertEventListener, so yours is likely just registered second.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the input. From a stacktrace I got by throwing an exception in `@PrePersist`, I think I remember there was no hibernate code involved in the call chain (at least from org.hibernate). I could be wrong and I should try it again to double check. But whatever, BeanValidation must be prepended after custom Listener's init code is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Interceptor could be the way to go :

```java
@Log
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class EntityInterceptorRegistration implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    private final Interceptor entityInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", entityInterceptor);
    }
}
```

```java
@Log
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class EntityInterceptor implements Interceptor, Serializable {
    [...]
    @Override
    public boolean onLoad(Object entity, Object id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
        [...]
        return Interceptor.super.onLoad(entity,id,state,propertyNames,types);
    }
    [...]
}
```